# Script or vCO workflow to create contiguous space on datastore cluster

Tags: vmware, vmware-server

Hey guys first time actually asking a question here and hope you guys can help as much as you have (unwillingly) in the past.

Currently when a request comes in through vRA for a large VM we have to move VM's on a datastore cluster to consolidate the free space for the new VM.  I would really love this to be somewhat automated where i could punch in the space i need and if it could fit it would move VM's around the ds cluster to make the space.

Its possible i'm missing something obvious that i can do but i have no idea.  I toyed around with the idea of putting a ds in maintenance mode letting it move VM's and then taking it out but that will cause a lot of VM's to move that might not need to be.

Any ideas are appreciate!  Thanks all.